# How do I optimize the Hourglass program from Hackerrank?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

**This is the hourglass problem which can be found on Hackerrank website.**

Here is a link to the problem : [Hourglass](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/2d-array)

Here is the code that I wrote for the Hourglass problem :

```
    public class Solution
    {
    public static int hourglass(int[][] a, int n)
    {
        int max = -999;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {         
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                boolean flag = false;

                if ((i+2) < n && (j+2) < n)
                {
                    sum += a[i][j] + a[i][j+1] + a[i][j+2] + a[i+1][j+1] + a[i+2][j] + a[i+2][j+1] + a[i+2][j+2];
                    flag = true;
                }
                if (sum > max && flag == true)
                    max = sum;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = 6;
        int[][] a = new int[6][6];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                a[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();

        int maxSum = hourglass(a, n);
        System.out.println(maxSum);
    }
}
```

**My Question**

Now, the above code compiled and ran successfully and even passed all the test cases. However, my code takes O(n^2) time (here the size of the matrix is 6, but if the size were n, then it would take O(n^2) time to finish.)

It takes O(n^2) time to create the array, and that I am not concerned about. What I am interested is to optimise the hourglass() method where it takes O(n^2) time to calculate the sum of the hourglass.

So, is there any way to implement the above problem with further optimisation?

Is it possible to solve the problem in O(n) time?

*In fact, I tried to solve the problem in O(n) time by removing the inner loop in the hourglass() method but it did not seem to work.*

**P.S.** I do not need a working code, all I need is some pointers to possible improvements (if any) or an algorithm at the most.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You have to calculate the sum for all hourglasses. And the number of hourglasses is `(n-2)^2` or `n^2-4n+4`. That means the number of hourglasses is O(n^2)

Comment: @Andreas thanks for pointing out where I should post my code for review. Actually I was looking for something like this for a long time, as I have a lot of code to put up for review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you're solution is already O(n).  You're defining "n" as though it were one side of the 2d array, but if you regarded n as a unique placement on your board, n is a combination of row * col.  Redefined this way, you can't beat O(n) on this problem.

You can, however, optimize some.  You're essentially laying a 3x3 tile onto a 6x6 board.  If a placement were to be defined by the top left corner of your 3x3 tile, then you're trying all 36 placements.  If you think about it, many of those placements would leave your tile hanging off the edge of the board.  You really only need to consider the first 4x4 positions rather than all 6x6 positions.  It's still an O(n) solution, but it would cut 36 iterations down to 16.

Comment: Yes I got your point! Thanks a lot... a small but subtle change. Mainly it will affect the performance when the value of N is large .